# confusion about surface integral using inverse of parameterized surface

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

**Problem :**

Let $S$ be surface which parameterized
$$S : r(u, v) = (2uv, u^2 - v^2, u^2 + v^2)\quad (u^2 +v^2 \leq 1)$$

Evaluate surface integral :
$$\iint_S (x^2 + y^2) dS$$

---

I tried to find original surface which doesn't depend on $u, v$.

Since
$$(2uv)^2 + (u^2 - v^2)^2 = (u^2 + v^2)^2$$
I find representation of $S$ without using $u, v$ like below :
$$S : z^2 = x^2 + y^2$$

and, since $0\leq z = u^2 + v^2 \leq 1$, we can choose $z=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ for surface $S$.

Then I tried to evaluate original surface integral, using $dS = \sqrt{2}dxdy$.

$$\begin{align} \iint_S (x^2 + y^2)dS &= \sqrt{2}\iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 1} (x^2 + y^2) dxdy \\ 
&= \sqrt{2} \times \frac{\pi}{2}\end{align}$$

But the answer of this problem is $\sqrt{2}\pi$, not $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\pi$. I think there is no such error, but my result is different.

Is there any mistake or error what I didn't catch?

Thank you.

Comment: Reviewing your work briefly, I don't find any flaws and computing the integral the long way also gives me your answer. But I could have made a mistake, too.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for your verify. But if I evaluate this integral without finding original surface $S$, it gives $\sqrt{2}\pi$. Can you try with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are more interested in the integral
$$
\int_S\,dS
$$
which is the surface area rather than rather than $\iint_S(x^2+y^2)\,dS$
but this does not matter for the resolution of the riddle.

That surface is a cone which we normally parametrize with
$$
s(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\[2mm]\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad x^2+y^2\le 1\,.
$$
With the parametrization
$$
r(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}2uv\\u^2-v^2\\u^2+v^2\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad u^2+v^2\le 1\,,
$$
we trace the same cone but this happens ***twice*** since
$$
r(u,v)=r(-u,-v)\,.
$$
To get the surface element we calculate as usual
$$
\partial_u\boldsymbol{r}\times\partial_v\boldsymbol{r}=4\begin{pmatrix}v\\u\\u\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}u\\-v\\v\end{pmatrix}=4\begin{pmatrix}2uv\\u^2-v^2\\-u^2-v^2\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
The length of this vector is $4\sqrt{2}\,(u^2+v^2)\,.$ Therefore
$$
dS=4\sqrt{2}\,(u^2+v^2)\,du\,dv\,.
$$
If we integrate naively over $u^2+v^2\le 1$ instead over half of that we think that the surface area is
$$
A=4\sqrt{2}\iint\limits_{u^2+v^2\le 1}(u^2+v^2)\,du\,dv=4\,\sqrt{2}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r^3\,dr\,d\varphi=2\,\sqrt{2}\,\pi
$$
which is ***two*** times the surface area of the [lateral surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone#Surface_area) of the cone as expected.

You can check easily that the same procedure using the unambiguous classical parametrization $s(x,y)$ leads to $\sqrt{2}\pi$ as it must.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. Is there any general idea to determine parameterization of surface has redundancy? (Twice in this problem, or fourth, etc.) In this problem, $r(u, v) = r(-u, -v)$ shows same cone happens twice, but I want to know general idea for other problems. If it is hard to determine, I will use original $u, v$-parameterization, not a classical $x, y$-parameterizaiton.

Comment: @bFur4list It took myself a while to spot it in this interesting example. General idea: know your weapon and know what you are doing.